# How to merge two different data frames columns based on str.contains()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have one dataframe called df_companies.

```
Òutput: 
    company     brand 
0   VW-Konzern  volkswagen
1   VW-Konzern  audi
2   VW-Konzern  bentley
3   VW-Konzern  bugatti
4   VW-Konzern  lamborghini
```

In the next step i receive two strings within a for loop through some string formatting. After that i am trying to check, if the 'companyName' string is contained in the column 'brand' of the dataframe 'df_companies'.

If so, then add the logo_url string two the dataframe df_companies into column 'image_url'.

```
for image in images:
    companyName = image['alt'].lower().split(' ', 1)[0]
    logo_url = image['src']

    df_companies['image_url'] = np.where(df_companies['brand'].str.contains(companyName), logo_url, 'other')
```

This works so far for the first row. For the rest of the remaining rows it only enters the string 'other' as defined above.

```
Output: 
        company     brand       image_url
0       VW-Konzern  volkswagen  https://imgr.volkswagen.png
1       VW-Konzern  audi        Other
2       VW-Konzern  bentley     Other
3       VW-Konzern  bugatti     Other
4       VW-Konzern  lamborghini Other
```

What i would like to achieve is the following output:

```
Output: 
        company     brand       image_url
0       VW-Konzern  volkswagen  https://imgr.volkswagen.png
1       VW-Konzern  audi        https://imgr.audi.png
2       VW-Konzern  bentley     https://imgr.bentley.png
3       VW-Konzern  bugatti     https://imgr.audi.png
4       VW-Konzern  lamborghini https://imgr.audi.png
```

The issue is that the 'companyName' string and the string in the 'brand' column of dataframe 'df_companies' only match partially, why i cannot use the common merge function.

Any ideas how to solve that issue?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your example is not clear, on your expected output i don't see the company name in the brand name, except for VW

Comment: This part is only done once: 

   `df_companies['image_url'] = np.where(df_companies['brand'].str.contains(companyName), logo_url, 'other')`


I would like to know, how this is done for every 'companyName' string, which i receive. 

Another example: 
`companyName = mercedes`
The Value in the original dataframe df_companoies in column 'brand' is: `mercedes-benz`

So how to merge that together?

Comment: This is not working because the last company will overwrite all the logo website that are not the one of the company by "others".
You can try to subset the dataframe by company, apply the changes and then concatenate it back to a new one

Comment: if you can provide the all the `companyName` values that you have, we can double check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex=True` within the `str.contains` method & even a partial name should match. For example as below

```
df['image_url'] = np.where(df['brand'].str.contains('au' , regex=True), 'logo_url', 'other')
```

**Output** I just used text `logo_url` instead of the url.

```
company     brand           image_url
VW-Konzern  volkswagen      other
VW-Konzern  audi            logo_url
VW-Konzern  bentley         other
VW-Konzern  bugatti         other
VW-Konzern  lamborghini     other
```

Answer (score 0):

I could find a solution. I had to put in `df_companies['image_url']`into the else condition of `np.where`insteaf of `'other'`.

```
df_companies['image_url'] = ''

    for image in images:

        companyName = image['alt'].lower().split(' ', 1)[0]
        logo_url = image['src']

        df_companies['image_url'] = np.where(df_companies['brand'].str.contains(companyName), logo_url, df_companies['image_url'],)
```

Afterwards i got the expected output:

```
Output:
    company     brand       image_url
0   VW-Konzern  volkswagen  https://imgr1.auto-motor-und-sport.de/Volkswagen-Logo-brandtreeIndexSmall-f4ae98d2-941118.jpg
1   VW-Konzern  audi        https://imgr1.auto-motor-und-sport.de/Audi-Logo-Neu-02-2019-brandtreeIndexSmall-44d434cb-1430808.jpg
2   VW-Konzern  bentley     https://imgr1.auto-motor-und-sport.de/Bentley-Logo-brandtreeIndexSmall-41a61902-702423.jpg
3   VW-Konzern  bugatti     https://imgr1.auto-motor-und-sport.de/Bugatti-Logo-brandtreeIndexSmall-252888c-946200.jpg
4   VW-Konzern  lamborghini https://imgr1.auto-motor-und-sport.de/Lamborghini-Logo-brandtreeIndexSmall-df88a8a3-945695.jpg
```